# When to use percent i method to create arrays with symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

In Ruby there is a nifty method of creating an array of symbols.
Percent i method.

```
%i[a b c]
```

I am working in a team based environment, and although I can see this being useful with a large list of array, I have this is being implemented for everything

```
a = %i[]    # Empty array
```

cancan abilities

```
  can :manage, :all
  cannot %i[create show update], AModel
  cannot %i[create], BModel
  cannot %i[show], CModel
```

Is it good to initialize all arrays using this methods or just

```
  cannot [:create, :show, :update], AModel
```

I know there is no 'right' way but I would like the pros and cons to help me decide

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `a = %i[]` makes no sense, it’s the same as `a = []`.

Comment: This is ruby: do it as you like. There is no impact on anything. just a matter of preference.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `can :manage, :all` can be written as `can *%i[manage all]` since you like `%i`.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the language itself, there are no important differences between the two, so it really comes down to a matter of preference. Personally, I think that the array of symbol literals (`[:create, :show, :update]`) looks more Ruby-like and that is what I'd use, but you should discuss it with your team. The most important part is being consistent, and you don't want to make the decision alone.

In the general case of when to use `%i` instead of writing out a literal array of symbols, I'd consider using the former if it was a list of symbols that had certain meaning, like a class constant or something, and there were more than just a couple. I've been using Ruby for a while now and until this question didn't really register the existence of `%i`, so it's relatively uncommonly used. It's maybe not in the average Rubyist's vocabulary, so that might be another reason to stay away from it.